# Turning book page like animation in slideshow using CSS3 and javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css-transitions

I have to create custom image slider using css and javascript. I have created something like shown in snippet.now my requirement is to make this slider look fancy.

How can i add 3d transition/Animation like turning a page or slicing into piece  animations when next slide comes using css3 and javascript?

```js
  var slideIndex = 0;
   
    showSlides();

  function showSlides() {
   
        var i;
        var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
        var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
        for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
            slides[i].style.display = "none";
        }
        slideIndex++;
        if (slideIndex > slides.length) { slideIndex = 1 }
        for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
            dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
        }
        slides[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
        dots[slideIndex - 1].className += " active";
        setTimeout(showSlides, 2000); // Change image every 2 seconds
    }
```

```css
* {box-sizing:border-box}
body {font-family: Verdana,sans-serif;}
.mySlides {display:none}

/* Slideshow container */
.slideshow-container {
  max-width: 1000px;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
}

/* Caption text */
.text {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 8px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

/* Number text (1/3 etc) */
.numbertext {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}

/* The dots/bullets/indicators */
.dot {
  height: 13px;
  width: 13px;
  margin: 0 2px;
  background-color: #bbb;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
}

.active {
  background-color: #717171;
}

/* Fading animation */
.fade {
  -webkit-animation-name: fade;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
  animation-name: fade;
  animation-duration: 1.5s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fade {
  from {opacity: .4}
  to {opacity: 1}
}

@keyframes fade {
  from {opacity: .4}
  to {opacity: 1}
}

/* On smaller screens, decrease text size */
@media only screen and (max-width: 300px) {
  .text {font-size: 11px}
}
```

```html
<div class="slideshow-container">

<div class="mySlides fade">
  <div class="numbertext">1 / 3</div>
  <img src="http://res.cloudinary.com/demo/image/upload/w_133,h_133,c_thumb,g_face/bike.jpg" style="width:100%">
  <div class="text">Caption Text</div>
</div>

<div class="mySlides fade">
  <div class="numbertext">2 / 3</div>
  <img src="http://demo.cloudimg.io/s/width/300/sample.li/boat.jpg" style="width:100%">
  <div class="text">Caption Two</div>
</div>

<div class="mySlides fade">
  <div class="numbertext">3 / 3</div>
  <img src="http://demo.cloudimg.io/s/resize/200/http://sample.li/ny.jpg" style="width:100%">
  <div class="text">Caption Three</div>
</div>

</div>
<br>

<div style="text-align:center">
  <span class="dot"></span>
  <span class="dot"></span>
  <span class="dot"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: here is use full for demo http://tympanus.net/Development/BookBlock/index.html# ,http://www.jqueryrain.com/2012/12/best-jquery-page-flip-book-effect-with-examples/

Comment: Thanks  parag parmmar ! but i want to write my own script and css so that i can customize it easily whenever needed.